# Count record views for a time period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB with a lot of records (of articles) and currently I keep track of how many times each record has been viewed by counting the views so I can sort on somehting like "see the top 5 most viewed articles"

This is done with a column of integers, and whenever the record is retrieved, the integer count increases by 1. 
This works fine but since the counting system is very simple, I can only see views of "all time".

I would like to have something like "see the top 5 most viewed articles this week".

The only way I can think of is to have a separate table which makes a record with the article Id and Date whenever an article is viewed, and then make a SELECT statement for a limited time period. 
This could easily work, but at the same time the table would be very large in no time.

Is there any better way of acomplishing the same thing? I've seen the sorting criteria on many websites, but I dont know how this is achieved.

Any thoughts or comments?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can use the table you describe, and periodically delete old entries to keep it from getting too large.

Comment: `select count(views) as large from activity_log group by views order by large desc limit 5`

Comment: I suggest a record for each view.  Some day down the road you may want to run queries based on the time of day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a row for each view of each article, you could have a row per day. When an article is viewed, you would do:

```
INSERT INTO article_views (article_id, date, views)
VALUES (@article, CURRENT_DATE(), 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views = views + 1;
```

Then to get the top 5 articles viewed in the past week:

```
SELECT article_id, SUM(views) total_views
FROM article_views
WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 day
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY total_views DESC
LIMIT 5
```

To keep the table from growing too large, you can delete old records periodically.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there an easy way to delete old records periodically? are should I delete them manually in the DB? The later, I would rather aviod.

Comment: You can use the MySQL event scheduler. Or a cron job that runs a mysql query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This seems like the optimal way :)